# Predicates and combined filters in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nspredicate

I'm not using Core Data currently, but I'm about to switch to it from Realm, if I'm sure a certain thing will work, which is vital to the way my application currently works. I have a model with two objects:

```
Message:
date - NSDate
text - String
images - One-to-many > Image

Image:
imageURL - String
message - Many-to-one > Image
```

I have a table view which displays both Images and Messages. I need to know what should go at a certain index path, for when UITableView wants to know. So I need to be able to perform a query akin to:

"Give me an ordered list of images and messages, messages sorted by their `date` and images sorted by their `message.date`".

How could I do this?

Comment: Will your tableView be grouped into sections?  If so, what will the section names be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't sort a mixed array with messages and images during coredata fetch request. Here is one possible way:

1. fetch messages and images separately
2. merge two arrays into one
3. sort the only one array `- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(id, id, void *))comparator context:(void *)context`

the function

```
 NSInteger sort(id item1, id item2, void *context) {
        int v1 = [item1 iskindofClass[message class]]?item1.data:item1.message.date;
        int v2 = [item2 iskindofClass[message class]]?item1.data:item1.message.date;
        if (v1 < v2)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        else if (v1 > v2)
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        else
            return NSOrderedSame;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be really slow if I had an array of say 10000 items?

Comment: @Andrew I don't know for sure. Better to run some test to find out